Confusion regarding Amenability and Weak Amenability
I was reading Todorov's notes about Herz-Schur Multipliers: Herz-Schur Multipliers and there is something I am finding weird related to (weak) amenability and the Fourier algebra.
On page 8, after Proposition 2.7 he says "$G$ is amenable if and only if the constant function $1$ can be approximated, uniformly on compact sets, by elements of $A(G)$".
On page 50, the definition of weak amenability is introduced as:
Definition $G$ is said to be weakly amenable if there is a net $u_i$ and a constant $C > 0$ such that $\|u_i\|_{\text{cbm}} \leq C$ and $u_i \rightarrow 1$ uniformly on compact sets.
The definition above says that the constant 1 function can be approximated, uniformly on compact sets, by elements of $A(G)$, which by the above mean $G$ is amenable. Thus weak amenability implies amenability which is a very absurd result.

What am I understanding wrong?


I think this is a typo; the correct statement is:
$G$ is amenable $\Leftrightarrow$ there is a net $(u_i)_{i}$ in $A(G)$ such that $u_i\rightarrow 1$ uniformly on compact sets and $\sup_{i} \|u_i\|_{A(G)}<+\infty$.
(In particular weak amenability is a weaker property then amenability).
Without the condition that net $(u_i)_i$ is bounded in $A(G)$ norm, the property you mention holds trivially for all discrete groups: simply take $u_i=1_{K_i}\in C_c(G)\subset A(G)$ for an increasing net of finite sets $K_i$ such that $\bigcup_i K_i=G$.

Thank you for clearing this up! I did know there had to be a norm bound somewhere, as it also exists in the formulation regarding approximate units on $A(\Gamma)$.

I have another question, I see sometimes weak amenability be defined for a net in $A(G)$ and other times for a net in $M_0A(G)$, do they give the same definition? Of course we have that $A(G) \subseteq M_0A(G)$, but what about the other direction, can we always change a net in $M_0A(G)$ to one in $A(G)$?

So: $\exists$ net $(u_i)i$ in $M_0 A(G)$ such that $u_i\to 1$ uniformly on compact sets and  $|u_i|{M_0 A(G)}\le C$? This is strictly weaker than weak amenability. In fact, this property hold for all locally compact groups: simply take $u_i=1$, which is a CB multiplier with $|1|_{M_0 A(G)}=1$.

Do you mean  condition $u_i\in C_c(G)\cap A(G)$?

Yes that was my misunderstanding, I must have misread the article then. Thank you a lot!
